# How to avoid white artifacts when use translucence attribute?

Tags: qt, artifacts

I want to make a translucent window in Qt:

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Popup| Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground,true);
```

But Once I set the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` to `true`, there will be white things on the four corners of each widget:

[image]

It appears whenever the mouse hover though the widget,or click on it.
How to avoid this ? If I set the `Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground` to `false`, the problem will be gone. But I need transparent window.
Thanks beforehand!

Comment: I seem unable to replicate this. Please provide more details, including what platform you're on.

Comment: my OS is Windows, I tried on WinXP  and Win7, they all have this issue. I use style sheet on these widgets too. And use anti-Aliased font: Arial.

Comment: I draw transparent black background in paintEvent. Maybe it is the black background make the white corners more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out myself. 
There are two reasons together that make these artifacts happen:
I have turned on the translucence background for the window ,and use QPainter to manually draw the window's rouned-corner background . When the mouse hover/press on the Children widgets, the update(QRect) the widget sent to window widget does not compute the background well.

When I use stylesheet to draw the background, problem solved :)